# Update Android embedded Wear app 1.x to 2.0

Tags: android, wear-os

I should update an embedded Wear App with Android 1.x to Android 2.0,
but reading the documentation i don't understand if the only alternative to support both versions is to create another standalone app.
Alternatively update excluding the version 1.x would lead me to hold the new app embedded?.
anyone have my same problem ?
sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding - I don't think so both version would be support at a time. If we have upgraded to wear2.0 then watch play store would be available then after you need to install application from watch play store only.

PS: We have to create 2 apk - one for mobile and another for Mobile. Then we have to use Multi distribution for release apk, check below link -

https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but if I understand well this might not be my case. Right now I don't have a stand alone app, it's embedded in my app and it's installed with the mobile app. If I decide to go with the decision to maintain both android wear 1.x and android wear 2 version, is it possible to embed android wear 2 or is it necessary to create a stand alone version and publish it on the wear store?

Comment: It's highly recommended to distribute a self-contained watch APK for Wear 2.0. Embedding the APK (1.x-style) is deprecated, and while AFAIK it will still work for the initial 2.0 release, it sounds like it may not continue to do so for long.

Comment: If you want to support both . Wear 1.x and wear 2.0 then.. you can embedded apk for 1.x and prepare second apk for wear 2.0.

Comment: wear apk would be same for 1.x and 2.0 . You just need to add flavors in gradle file of wear apk.                                                                                              Read - [link](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/app-distribution.html#publish)  Under section - "Support in the Gradle file"